# find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash 


echo "please enter a path where to search:"
read myPath

touch --date "2012-01-01" /tmp/start
touch --date "2012-01-01" /tmp/end

until  [ "$myPath" = $(pwd) ] 
do
echo "please enter a correct path where to search:"
read myPath
done


RESULT= "$(find  $HOME "-type -f" -newer /tmp/start -not -newer tmp/end)"

echo $RESULT
```

When I'm trying to execute it I'm getting:

```
find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter
TimeStamp: line 17: : command not found
```

Comment: You almost certainly want `/tmp/end` rather than `tmp/end`

Comment: There can't be a space after the equal sign in the assignment to `RESULT`. In the `find` and `echo` statements, the variables should be quoted: `find "$HOME" ...` and `echo "$RESULT"`. There's nothing in what you've posted that would give the "command not found" error. You prompt for `myPath` then force it to equal `pwd` then don't use it, but use `$HOME` instead. This doesn't make any sense. You don't need the first `echo` and `read` since the `until` loop will do what you want. Having `/tmp/start` and `/tmp/end` have the same date doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Some versions of `find` allow you to supply a date as an argument so you don't need temporary files for comparison. The title of your question is friendly but it tells nothing about the question.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, why do you have `-type -f` *outside* the quotes? And it's 
`-type f` not `-type -f` (no dash before the `f`)

Try this:

```
"$(find $HOME -type f -newer /tmp/start -not -newer tmp/end)"
```

Comment: It's not outside the quotes. Inside `$()` there's a new quoting context. So the `$()` is inside the outer set of quotes and the `-type f` is *inside* the inner set of quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
"$(find $HOME -type f -newer /tmp/start -not -newer tmp/end)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
RESULT= "$(find  $HOME "-type -f" -newer /tmp/start -not -newer tmp/end)"
```

#### find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter

Several things: Remove the quotes around `-type -f`. I'm not sure why you put them there. The correct argument for the `-type` parameter should be `f` and not `-f`.

#### TimeStamp: line 17: : command not found

You did a touch on `/tmp/end`, but you're looking at `tmp/end`. This is saying the same thing as `$PWD/tmp/end`. You need a slash at the front to anchor this to the root of the directory structure. You need `/tmp/end` and not `tmp/end`.

Try:

```
RESULT= "$(find "$HOME" -type f -newer /tmp/start -not -newer /tmp/end)"
```

Comment: thank you all ,changed to echo "please enter a path where to search:" read myPath touch --date "2012-01-01" /tmp/start touch --date "2012-01-01" /tmp/end until [ "$myPath" = "$HOME" ] do echo "please enter a correct path where to search:" read myPath done RESULT="$(find "$HOME" -type -f -newer /tmp/start -not -newer /tmp/end)" echo "$RESULT"  but still the same error

Comment: @user912134 Did you change the `-f` to `f` in the `-type` parameter?